# Разбить страницы ViewPager на группы

Tags: android, android-viewpager

У меня есть ViewPager и на нём 12 страниц. 6 принадлежат одной группе и 6 другой.
Как бы так красиво разделить страницы на группы?
Можно ли сверху поставить ещё один текст, который при перелистывании 1-5 страниц не будет перелистываться. А когда перелистывание с 6 на 7 страницу он тоже перелистывался, уведомляя, что поменялась группа страниц.

Answer (score 0):

Вы поверх табов поставить textview на всю ширину и когда у вас будет меняться фрагмент с 5 на 6 менять текст в этом textview. Вы всегда можете узнать номер страницы в методе `onPageSelected`.

Comment: Но тогда это будет не красиво... Просто резкое изменение текста, хотелось бы, чтобы он анимировано вместе со страницей менялся.

Comment: @Алексей, вы наверное не сможете оставлять комментарии под ответом, так что вот вам [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48662/discussion-on-answer-by-pavel163---viewpager--).

Comment: Ну это уже другой вопрос. Посмотрите тогда в сторону ObjectAnimator